# Zend Studio 8 uploads IDE specific files to server on startup

Tags: zend-studio

I decided to give Zend Studio 8 a try - I really liked 5.5 and used it until my hard drive got fried and the Zend sales person wouldn't point me to any executables since it was EOL - but keep running into all sorts of bugs.

The issue I am having now though is that I just noticed several files and dirs that had not been in my docroot or a website I am working on prior to me closing and reopening ZS 8.  Earlier this morning I created a new remote project, made some changes to some code, ran a svn update to sync my repo - 1 file was updated (fileA.php) - and committed those changes to an svn repo.  I ran a svn status after the fact and nothing showed up. Several hrs later I had to make another change and so I fired up ZS 8 and - before making ANY changes or even opening a file in the editor - I just happened to run an svn status and saw the following:

```
$ svn status
?  .project
?  .buildpath
?  .settings
M  fileA.php
```

After some digging, all I can come up with is that when I started up the IDE the 2nd time, it uploaded those files/dirs above to the server and reverted fileA.php back to the state it had been in before I ran the svn update that ingested another user's changes.

Any idea what is happening and how I can prevent it from make these unintended changes to the code on the server itself?  In ZS 5.5 it would always update itself w/the code that was in the project paths.

I should point out that no one else has access to the dir I am working in and no one else is using ZS to edit their code.  So the only way those files got there was from my usage of ZS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I don't use svn too much, I'm a git man. Assuming that svn:ignore works the same as a .gitignore (more or less) you can tell svn to ignore certain files. So:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore ./the_project_dir
```

opens a text editor

then add in

```
.project
.buildpath
.settings
```

and save.

It :should: no longer track project files that are created by your IDE, and so those files shouldn't get pushed up to the server.

found on: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm

Comment: Hey Francis, thanks for the info about svn, I didn't even think about it. I was more looking for how to stop Zend from putting files on the server that shouldn't be there.  I appreciate the info though!

Comment: there is no way to stop the IDE from creating files unfortunately. iot needs them to track what is and is not a project. You could, open each file independently and the ide wouldn't make those files. Kinda a lame solution though.